# Get Transformed and Actual Pixel Height and Width of each bar in Matplotlib Bar Plot

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, pixel

I have a bar plot, and I try to get the pixel height and width of each bar by:

```
def get_dims(bars):

    fig = plt.gcf()
    fig.canvas.draw()
    r = fig.canvas.get_renderer()
    heights = [bar.get_window_extent(r).height for bar in bars]
    widths = [bar.get_window_extent(r).width for bar in bars]
    return widths, heights
```

I use these dimensions to then crop an image and paste over the bar. However, it seems like get_window_extents does not return the ACTUAL pixel height and width because the final image ends up like this:

[image: Sample Image]

What do I need to call to get the True display size in pixels? Am I using the wrong fig?

Comment: I should add that 'get_extents()' returns the same pixel info. So that is no help. There must be a data_transform that returns the proper dimensions.

Comment: Furthermore, it is not just a proportional change. When I multiply by 1.4 for instance, some bars are much too big and some are too small. I need to actually get the right dimensions, because _axes.py, patches.py, and _base.py in matplotlib need to return the proper Rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Patch is the object with `get_extents()`. The Rectangle has `get_height()`, and now you can use a proportional factor. It would still be nice to somehow gain the scale, which the plot is using.